# why pull-right class not working on bootstrap version 4.1.0?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Previously We used bootstrap version 3+. Now we using 4.1.0. When I try to Align using pull-right and pull-left , its not working. Even I tried with float- right/ float left its not working.   [image: Click here to see image] (I mentioned in the Image where it displaying and where I want it to be displayed)

Codes here:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </a>
    <div class="header_text float-left ">Home</div>
    <div class="header_text float-right">Company Name</div>
    <div class="navbar-custom-menu ">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle float-right" data-toggle="dropdown"> <img src="./Images/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image"> <span class="hidden-sm">Welcome</span> </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

In above code, I tried with `pull-right` and `pull-left` at first, then after 
 few google search I used `float-left` and `float-right`.still My expected result not come. kindly help

For @soheilPs reference  [image: I add image here]

Comment: V4 rely on flexbox so better forget floating and consider flexbox alignment

Comment: you should have to read this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS? Specifically for the navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ml-auto and mr-auto

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
  <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </a>
  <div class="header_text mr-auto">Home</div>
  <div class="header_text ml-auto">Company Name</div>
  <div class="navbar-custom-menu ">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle ml-auto" data-toggle="dropdown"> <img src="./Images/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image"> <span class="hidden-sm">Welcome</span> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. Ur one working for me. but  to my left and to my right Home and Company name display like next line . I dont know how to add picture here so ,I edit my qstn and add that picture for ur reference

Comment: I'm glad that it helped.

Comment: I appreciate if you help me to  make it display like single line

Comment: there might be a conflict somewhere in your code, when I test it it works fine in one line: https://jsfiddle.net/mssoheil88/2cj7yjdj/

Comment: ya dnt knw why.. will check my self later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Check the changelog:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities

> Added .float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none} classes for responsive
>   floats and removed .pull-left and .pull-right since they’re redundant
>   to .float-left and .float-right.

So in your case it should be

```
class="float-sm-right"
```

Comment: I tried ur one not working for me